# Syncing pdf with vscode external viewer

Tags: pdf, forward-inverse-search, visual-studio-code

Setup: I'm using visual studio code with LaTeX Workshop extension to write latex. I use an external pdf viewer mainly because I want to see the pdf on a different screen. Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Problem: I can't get syncing to open the pdf on the text that corresponds to the cursor in the editor, nor can I go from a word in the editor to the same word in the pdf or vise versa.

I've tried: I don't mind which pdf viewer to use to get the sync to work, I've tried the default document reader, atril, zathura, and okular.
I've tried following the extension's [wiki](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/View) and other online suggestions so I might be doing something wrong.
I don't mind using something other than synctex, as long as it works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does `evince` not re-render the pdf when it is updated by LaTeX on Ubuntu?

Comment: @oliversm evince is the default right? it doe's rerender, I should have been more clear in what I mean by sync. I've edited the question to make it clear

Comment: I see the problem more clearly now. I don't think this is a problem with the default pdf viewer, as I think that the viewers in LaTeX IDEs which allow you to map from the source code to the documents aren't displaying a PDF. I think these viewing windows and the syncing is a feature of the IDE and not the PDFs (the PDFs I suspect don't actually contain the information in a structure to facilitate this). As an example, I know TexStudio (and likely others) have the option that their built in view can be undocked from the IDE and hence viewed in another window. This may be worth investigating.

Comment: thanks @oliversm, in TexStudio I would use this all the time with the internal viewer in a different window. In addition, however, I managed to get it working with some other viewers. I don't recall which ones, unfortunately.